# passing in a different value for argument for recursive function in bash?

Tags: bash

say I have the following:

```
n=10
function decrement {
    if [ $n -eq 0 ]; then
        echo recurse_done
    else
        echo $n
        decrement $(( $n-1 ))
    fi
}

decrement n
```

above would create a infinite call to *decrement* function and `n` would not decrement. I searched around and found `function $(( some_arithemtic_operation ))`, apparently it does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide what argument you're passing to your function: is it a variable *name* or a *value*?

If it's a name, indirect variable expansion is called for:

```
function decrement {
    local var=$1      
    if [[ ${!var} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo recurse_done
    else
        echo ${!var}
        declare "$var=$(( ${!var} - 1))"
        decrement $var
    fi
}
decrement n
```

If it's a value, your life is simpler

```
function decrement { 
    local value=$1
    if [[ $value -eq 0 ]]; then 
        echo recurse done
    else 
        echo $value
        decrement $((value-1))
    fi
}
decrement $n
```

But why is this recursive at all? `seq $n -1 1` will count down from $n to 1

Comment: That's a curious downvote...